# Does setting channel_priority to "strict" affect all Conda environments?

Tags: conda, config, channel

I created a Conda environment with R using [the **conda-forge** channel instructions](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#how-can-i-install-packages-from-conda-forge):

1. `conda config --add channels conda-forge`
2. `conda config --set channel_priority strict`

**Question**: It seems that channel priority also affects the base environment as I am now not able to install or update any packages from the **base** env using `conda update ...` or `conda install`

Is the configuration setting `channel_priority` global? i.e., does it affect all Conda environments?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is a global setting. If you don't want it to be global, then activate the environment for which you wish to make the specific setting change, then use the `--env` flag. E.g.,

```bash
conda activate myenv
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
```

And yes, switching to **conda-forge** as your highest priority channel when your **base** was originally from Anaconda is formidable. Better off leaving **base** with the **defaults** channel prioritized or switching to [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge).