# How to get "conda update --all" to install using conda-forge instead of anaconda channel?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda-forge

When I run `conda update --all`, packages from anaconda channel are updated by default. I will prefer to have conda-forge channel by default because the packages are more up to date.

How do I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use the `--channel conda-forge` parameter?

Comment: If you do that, the next time you run "conda update --all", the package will be downgraded to anaconda version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `conda-forge` channel by default, `conda-forge` should have a higher priority than `defaults` channel.

Check the `~/.condarc`

```
cat ~/.condarc
```

It will return something like this

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
channel_priority: flexible
```

Change the channel order from `~/.condarc` so that `conda-forge` is the first channel

```
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults 
channel_priority: flexible
```

Or run the command line equivalent

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

```
Warning: 'conda-forge' already in 'channels' list, moving to the top
```

Next time when you run `conda update --all`, it will search from the `conda-forge` channel before `defaults` channel.

[Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html) explains how conda collect the packages from different channels.

**Additional**

You should consider setting `channel_priority` as `strict`, currently `flexible` is the default. Based on the conda documentation, `strict` will be the default in the next major version bump, conda 5.0.

```
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

To learn what channel_priority does, run `conda config --describe channel_priority`

```
channel_priority (ChannelPriority)
Accepts values of 'strict', 'flexible', and 'disabled'. The default
value is 'flexible'. With strict channel priority, packages in lower
priority channels are not considered if a package with the same name
appears in a higher priority channel. With flexible channel priority,
the solver may reach into lower priority channels to fulfill
dependencies, rather than raising an unsatisfiable error. With channel
priority disabled, package version takes precedence, and the
configured priority of channels is used only to break ties. In
previous versions of conda, this parameter was configured as either
True or False. True is now an alias to 'flexible'.

channel_priority: flexible
```

Also, note that this is a global setting. Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66390775/does-setting-channel-priority-to-strict-affect-all-conda-environments), if this should only be applied to a specific conda environment, activate the env and add `--env` in your script

```
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
```